# Trying to use sc-cli directly from path in polkadot-v0.9.28

Tags: parachain

I am trying to build a parachain using `polkadot-v0.9.28` with the `sc-cli` lib in my project. I am trying this to hardcode a CORS origin in the `run_cmd` module.

I am doing all this because defining origins using the CORS flag simply doesn't work for any origin besides all or default.

But I am getting build errors and can't see how to try fixing it.
[image] [image]

Can I try hardcoding the CORS origin another way? Any help is appreciated :)